# How can i make a hash top list in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

How can i make a hashtag top list in PHP?

i have a table  "posts"

this table contains 3 fields (id, text, hash)

the data like this

```
id   => 1
text => i'm from #us
hash => ,us

id   => 2
text => i #love #us
hash => ,love ,us 

id   => 3
text => i will travel to #us cus i #love it
hash => ,us ,love

id   => 4
text => i will go to #us #now 
hash => ,us ,now
```

i wanna show data like this

top hash

```
us
love
now
```

Comment: What's not working in your code?

Comment: You don't want a setup like this. You should have a setup like this: `posts (id, text)`, `tags (id, tag)`, and `relationships (id, post_id, tag_id)`. Then you can sort the `relationships` table by `tag_id DESC` and pull the top 3 most used.

Comment: There's no reason for a `tags` table when it stores no information but an unnecessary surrogate primary key. Nor does the `relationships` table need a `id` column; `post_id, tag` is a primary key on its own. It seems you have developed a habit of adding an `id` column to every table even when it's not needed.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. But it might make sense to use a table if the programmer intends to ultimately store more data than just a tag name, e.g. if he/she were to associate the tag with other information. You could also have a column in the `tags` table called `count` that gets updated periodically (or whenever a post is added/updated, which is probably less frequent than the top hashes are accessed), which would maybe speed up the queries? Not sure about that.

Comment: i tryed `<?php
$select_hash = $mysqli->query("SELECT `hash`, COUNT(`hash`) AS `frequency` FROM `posts` GROUP BY `hash` ORDER BY `frequency` DESC LIMIT 30");
$num_hash = $select_hash->num_rows;
if($num_hash){
while ($rows_hash = $select_hash->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)){

$id_hash             = $rows_hash ['id'];
$hash_hash             = $rows_hash ['hash'];

$hash = explode(",", $hash_hash);

if($hash[1]){
?>
<a href="hash.php?hash=<? echo $hash[1]; ?>" class="link">#<? echo $hash[1]; ?></a> <br />
<?
}
}
}
?>`

Comment: @MahmoudSamy, I can't read your code in this comment... mind shooting me an e-mail? wyattstorch 42 [at] outlook [dot] com

Comment: Here's a demo file that contains several helpful functions, for your reference. Let me know if you need help with anything. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28836420/hashblog.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sql = new MySQLi('localhost', 'root', '', 'database');
    // A MySQLi connection

/* Database setup:
`posts`
    `id`
    `text`

`tags`
    `tag`
    `post_id`
*/

function add_post ($text, $tags = array ()) {
    global $sql;

    $sql->query('INSERT INTO `posts` (`text`) VALUES ("'.$sql->real_escape_string($text).'");');
        // Insert the post into the posts table
    $postID = $sql->insert_id;
        // Capture its id

    if (count($tags) != 0) {
        foreach ($tags as &$tag) {
            $tag = $sql->real_escape_string($tag);
        }
        unset($tag);
            // Escape every tag

        $sql->query('INSERT INTO `tags` (`tag`, `post_id`) VALUES ("'.implode('", '.$postID.'), ("', $tags).'", '.$postID.');');
            // Insert the tags associated with this post as records in the tags table
    }
}

// If/when you write update_post and delete_post functions, you will need to manage the tags associated with them as well
// Probably it's best to use a relational system like InnoDB

function get_top_tags ($num = 3) {
    global $sql;

    $result = $sql->query('SELECT `tag`, COUNT(`tag`) AS `frequency` FROM `tags` GROUP BY `tag` ORDER BY `frequency` DESC LIMIT '.(int) $num.';');
        // Get the tags in order of most to least frequent, limited to $num

    $tags = array ();
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $tags[] = $row['tag'];
    }
        // Turn them into an array
    return $tags;
}

// Example usage:
add_post('This is a new post.', array ('this', 'post', 'new'));
add_post('This is an old post.', array ('this', 'post'));
add_post('That is a medium-aged post.', array ('post'));
?>
<h1>Top Tags</h1>
<ol>
<?php
foreach (get_top_tags(3) as $tag) {
?>
    <li><?php echo $tag; ?></li>
<?php
}
?>
</ol>
<!-- Should print
1. post
2. this
3. new
-->
```

Let me know if you need help with that. Untested code, so not sure if it works or not.